# Implentation of GoogleMaps in Native Application

Tags: javascript, cordova

I implented Google Maps over the Web Application successfully using HTML , JavaScript .Its also working well over Android Browser.
But on packaging this application into a native Android application the Maps arent loading ! Following is the Code for browser.
When packaged as a Native App with Cordova , no results and one error also states that Uncaught Reference : google not defined in line 22.
Please help me out over this , what modifications are required at pacakging !
Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<style type="text/css">
  html { height: 100% }
  body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
  #map-canvas { height: 100% }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDY0kkJiTPVd2U7aTOAwhc9ySH6oHxOIYM&sensor=false">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
      zoom: 8
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
        mapOptions);
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map-canvas"/>
</body>
</html>
```